# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 35 bytes) in /home/content/08/10674308/html/Arraytest.php on line 15

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am getting a fatal error. What am missing here? Thanks in advance for any help. I am learning. I am trying to test to see what dates are open between certain dates.

```
<?php
$query = 'SELECT venueprofile.venuename, venueprofile.capacity, venueprofile.contact,          venueprofile.EmailAddress, venueprofile.tele, venueprofile.st, venueprofile.city,        showdate.show_date, showdateid'
    . ' FROM `venueprofile` '
    . ' INNER JOIN `showdate` ON venueprofile.venueid = showdate.venueid'
    . ' WHERE show_date BETWEEN \'2013-06-15\' AND \'2013-06-25\''
    . ' AND capacity BETWEEN 500 AND 3000 '
    . ' ';


$startDate = '$date1'; 
$enddate = '$date2'; 
$dates = array($startDate); 
while ($startDate != $enddate) { 
$startDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($startDate . ' +1 day')); 
$dates[] = date; 
} 
; 


$bookings = array("2013-06-16","2013-06-20");
foreach ($dates as $date) { 
if (in_array($date, $bookings)) { echo ""; } 
else { echo $date . " is Open\n";}}

?>
```

Comment: With the code you've posted, your dates are invalid, leading to an infinite loop

Comment: Why is there a `$query`? AFAICS it is never used...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$startDate = '$date1'; 
$enddate = '$date2';
```

This doesn't work as expected; the single quotes prevent variable interpolation. Also, you don't need the quotes.

```
$startDate = $date1; 
$enddate = $date2;
```

Furthermore, I would recommend changing your loop condition.

```
while ($startDate < $enddate) {
```

Doing so could prevent issues when `$startDate > $enddate` before the loop starts.

Lastly, the following statement doesn't work:

```
$dates[] = date;
```

`date` is a constant which you most likely have not defined. You probably meant this:

```
$dates[] = $startDate;
```

Comment: Sam, thanks the help correcting this error. I made those changes. I don't have a very good handle on this and still trying to piece it together. I am trying to get the open dates between date 1 and date 2 to go to results. I am getting a blank (echos "is Open") Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the problems that Jack has already pointed out, it seems to me it would have been a lot more efficient to use just a single loop and avoid having to build up that array of dates.

So something like this:

```
$bookings = array("2013-06-16","2013-06-20");

$startDate = $date1; 
$enddate = $date2; 

while ($startDate <= $enddate) { 
  if (!in_array($startDate, $bookings)) {
    echo $startDate . " is Open\n";
  }
  $startDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($startDate . ' +1 day')); 
}
```

Or did you need the `$dates` array for some other purpose?

Comment: Thanks James for your suggestion. This works also.